# How to configure custom type Azure FrontDoor with Application Gateway in backend?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I need to configure azure Front door and at backed we having two Application Gateway and while hitting Front Door endpoint traffic not reaching to Application Gateway.
while we have tried with WebApp it is working fine but when we use AGIC it is not responding.

NOTE: We are using AGIC (Application Gateway Ingress Controller).

We have tried with Web Apps it is reaching the destination but with Application Gateway at backend , it is not reaching the destination. :-[While hitting Front door getting this error]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An outage error was caused when endpoints were not reachable via the front door.  Replicate the same with two application gateway endpoints via the front door.
Solution is keep **origin details as Custom** and **Host Name as DNS name of Applicaiton gateway hostname**

Step1:
Hosted two application gateway connection which are up and running
[image]

Step2:
Establishing connection for Front Door CDN service
[image]

Step3:
Gateway configurations for Origin group and added both Application Gateway End Point details.
[image]

**Origin Type: Custom

Host Name: Provide Public IP

Origin Host Name: Application Gateway URL**
Find details from the Application Gateway service

[image]

Testing URL from Applicaiton Gateway URL directly:
[image]

The same from Front Door URL
[image]

[image]

Comment: How about using custom domain? Can we add cert in both Front Door and AGIC as well?